# Can you use Gitlab CI / CD to build a Vue page and host it using Gitlab pages?

Tags: vue.js, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I have uploaded my code for a Vuejs site to Gitlab and if I build it using the Vuejs ui I get a valid website and everything works fine. How would I build my website using Gitlabs CI / CD?

Comment: https://about.gitlab.com/2017/09/12/vuejs-app-gitlab/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it: https://about.gitlab.com/2017/09/12/vuejs-app-gitlab/
Thank you, Billal Begueradj!